# Were there any marine/aquatic dinosaurs?

Tags: marine-biology, palaeontology, dinosaurs

Most dinosaurs were terrestrial, but there were a couple of groups of arboreal and [flying dinosaurs](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/17546/42780) (microraptors, birds etc).

I have read that the theory that Brachiosaurids were aquatic has been largely discredited<sup>1</sup>, but that Spinosaurids *were* probably semi-aquatic<sup>2</sup>.

Excluding modern marine birds (e.g. penguins etc.), **were there any other marine/aquatic dinosaurs?**

---

**Note:** I am aware that the marine reptiles *mesosaurs, phytosaurs, mosasaurs, dolichosaurs, Icthyosaurs, thalattosaurs, Sauropterygia* (*placodonts, nososaurs, plesiosaurs* etc), *Choristodera* were not part of Dinosauria.

---

*References:*

1. - [*Three new sauropod dinosaurs from the Upper Jurassic of Colorado*](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=3285&context=gbn), Great Basin Naturalist.
   - *The Physiology of Dinosaurs: Circulatory and Respiratory Function in the Largest Animals Ever to Walk the Earth*, Respiratory Care
   - *A note on the habits of sauropods*, Annals and Magazine of Natural History
   - [*Tipsy punters: sauropod dinosaur pneumaticity, buoyancy and aquatic habits*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1810024), Proceedings of the Royal Society of London
2. - [*Oxygen isotope evidence for semi-aquatic habits among spinosaurid theropods*](https://pubs.geoscienceworld.org/gsa/geology/article-abstract/38/2/139/130188/oxygen-isotope-evidence-for-semi-aquatic-habits?redirectedFrom=fulltext), Geology
   - [*Semiaquatic adaptations in a giant predatory dinosaur*](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/345/6204/1613.abstract), Science
   - *Convergent evolution of jaws between spinosaurid dinosaurs and pike conger eels*, Acta Palaeontologica Polonica
   - *Functional Morphology of Spinosaur 'crocodile-Mimic' Dinosaurs*, Journal of Vertebrate Paleontology

Comment: How about the [mosasaurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosasaur) for example?

Comment: @Remi.b mosasaurs were squamates, not dinosaurs: [*Mosasauroid phylogeny under multiple phylogenetic methods provides new insights on the evolution of aquatic adaptations in the group*](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0176773), PLOS ONE

Comment: Fair point! I am wondering why this post has been down voted.

Comment: [Hesperornithes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesperornithes) could be a good example but they are *Aves* (a "basal branch") if I am not mistaken. They are not modern birds though. Would you accept it as an answer?

Comment: @Remi.b ah, thanks! I was thinking of pre K-T extinction dinosaurs when I posted the question, which this is, so yes I would - unless someone responds with a larger list of examples :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of specimens of a dinosaur species named *Liaoningosaurus paradoxus* that have been found with fish in their stomachs and skeletal features suggesting it was at least semi-aquatic.  It is a member of the ankylosaurian dinosaurs from the early Cretaceous period of China.

From [Fish Hunting Ankylosaurs( Dinosauria,Ornithischia) from the Cretaceous of China](http://www.en.cnki.com.cn/Article_en/CJFDTotal-JSDZ201602028.htm):

> With elongate and fork-like denticles of cheek tooth crowns,L.
>   paradoxus has a dentition capable of penetrating into animals like
>   small fishes. The carnivorous adaptation of the dinosaur is also
>   supported by the ungual modification to a sharp claw in both the
>   fore-and hind-limbs. The evolution of a shield-like ventral armor
>   plate and the loose sacrum-pelvic connection suggest that L. paradoxus
>   may have adopted an aquatic way of life,using the ventral armor plate
>   to protect the body from underwater attacks; as such,the open suture
>   between the neural arch and centrum of the vertebrae cannot be used to
>   indicate the juvenile nature of the type specimen. L. paradoxus is the
>   first carnivorous ornithischian dinosaur since dinosaur was first
>   known in the 18th century and represents not only the first aquatic or
>   semi aquatic example of armored dinosaurs but also the smallest
>   species of ornithischian dinosaur so far known.

[image]

Image Source: [[Paleontology • 2016] Liaoningosaurus paradoxus • Fish Hunting Ankylosaurs (Dinosauria, Ornithischia) from the Cretaceous of China](http://novataxa.blogspot.com/2016/08/liaoningosaurus.html)

Answer (score 2):

I found this wikipedia page which lists a few more examples:

> Only a few nonavian dinosaurs are thought to have been semiaquatic. The combination of being oviparous and endothermic seems to have prevented the evolution of fully aquatic dinosaurs.
>
> - Theropoda
> - Paraves
>
>   - Avialae
>
>     - †*Ichthyornis* - a toothed ornithuran analog of modern seabirds such as gulls and petrels
>     - †Hesperornithes - a mostly flightless group of diving bird-like ornithurans
>   - †Dromaeosauridae
>
>     - †*Halszkaraptor* - a mallard-sized basal dromaeosaurid from Mongolia with flipper-like forelimbs
> - †Megalosauria
>
>   - †Spinosauridae - thought to be piscivores, the group had crocodile-like skulls and includes some of the largest known carnivorous dinosaurs
> - †Ornithischia
> - †Ornithopoda
>
>   - †Hadrosauriformes
>
>     - †*Lurdusaurus* - an unusually heavy-bodied and short-limbed iguanodont conjectured to have been similar in lifestyle to the modern hippopotamus
>
> [List of semi-aquatic tetrapods: Non-avian dinosaurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_semiaquatic_tetrapods#Nonavian_dinosaurs)

Chapter 23 of [New Perspectives on Horned Dinosaurs: The Royal Tyrrell Museum Ceratopsian Symposium](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OWpQW_WhPAsC&pg=PA328&lpg=PA328&dq=semi-aquatic), *"A Semi-Aquatic Life Habit for Psittacosaurus*, describes the evidence suggesting *Psittacosaurus* was semi-aquatic.

P57-59 of [Discovering Dinosaurs: Evolution, Extinction, and the Lessons of Prehistory](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=moOBFoBAZlgC&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=aquatic+dinosaur) suggests some hadrosaurs may have been semi-aquatic:

> [image]

---

| Dinosaur | Illustration |
| --- | --- |
| Icthyornis | [image] |
| Hesperornithes | [image] |
| Halszkaraptor | [image] |
| Spinosaurus | [image] |
| Lurdusaurus | [image] |
| Psittacosaurus | [image] |

Answer (score 1):

The only example I could find for the moment are [Hesperornithes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesperornithes). Hesperornithes are actually part of the *Aves* clade (see [here on tolweb.org](http://tolweb.org/Aves/15721)) but they are not modern bird species as they existed during the Cretaceaus.

[image]

Note that there are examples of aquatic species in *Squamata* (*Squamata* are not *Dinosauria*) though such as the [mosasaurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosasaur) for example.

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest discovery, [Nature (Published: 29 April 2020), Tail-propelled aquatic locomotion in a theropod dinosaur](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2190-3), *Spinosaurus* was probably aquatic or at least semi-aquatic. See also [this video](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-01304-w).