# Was the dodo a dinosaur?

Tags: taxonomy, palaeontology

I've always believed that the dodo was a dinosaur, I don't know exactly why. I've done some searching on the internet, but except for toy stores selling "Dodo the Dinosaur's" I didn't find anything very useful of which I could conclude if the dodo was a dinosaur or not.

So, was the dodo a dinosaur or not? And if the dodo wasn't a dinosaur, why do people say it's a dinosaur?

(I couldn't find a related tag, I think 'palaeontology' was the closest to what I needed)

Comment: It was a bird, and is now extinct. Typing 'dodo' in the Google search engine yielded the Wikipedia entry as the number 1 hit.

Comment: I've read the wikipedia page, but it doesn't say anything about it being a dinosaur or not. Which could point to the direction that the dodo wasn't a dinosaur. But I'm wondering why stores say it's a dinosaur. Where does that come from?

Comment: Perhaps you would have more success posting your query in ToyStores StackExchange, or PeopleWhoSayThings StackExchange? In this forum for Biology StackExchange I don't think you will encounter anyone with the appropriate expertise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes, dodos were dinosaurs, but that probably doesn't quite mean what you think it does.**

Dodos were birds, [closely related to pigeons](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2148/14/136). All [birds are dinosaurs](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00114-004-0570-4#/page-1).

Comment: Thanks! Now I get it. Never knew I've seen so many living dinosaurs ;)

Comment: @snake [This post](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35370/if-dinosaurs-could-have-feathers-would-they-still-be-reptiles) will probably help to understand the possible confusion with the term dinosaur.