# What's the most recent common ancestor of reptiles and humans?

Tags: genetics, evolution, human-evolution, herpetology

In the Phylogeny of humans and reptiles, what is/are some of the most recent common ancestors?

[image]

Comment: related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/82206/why-arent-mammals-and-reptiles-considered-amphibians?r=SearchResults&s=14|11.8981, https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/47957/why-are-turtles-classified-as-reptiles-and-not-amphibians/47968?r=SearchResults&s=15|11.3526#47968

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the [amniote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amniote) common ancestor.

Amniotes are the group of organisms that have an amnion, a specific membrane around the egg, among other features. This includes reptiles, mammals, etc. but excludes amphibians and fish as indicated in your tree.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amniote) says:

> **The first amniotes, referred to as "basal amniotes", resembled small lizards and evolved from the amphibian reptiliomorphs about 312 million years ago,[7] in the Carboniferous geologic period.** Amniotes spread around Earth's land and became the dominant land vertebrates.[7] They soon diverged into synapsids and sauropsids, which persist today. The oldest known fossil synapsid is Protoclepsydrops from about 312 million years ago,[7] while the oldest known sauropsid is probably Paleothyris, in the order Captorhinida, from the Middle Pennsylvanian epoch (c. 306–312 million years ago).

That citation 7 points to [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/mbe/article/24/1/26/1070944), which used paleontological data to assign time estimates to various diversification events inferred from molecular phylogenies; this allowed them to approximately estimate the time of emergence of amniotes from the amphibian clade.

Comment: Could you please add in the `[7]` citation?

Comment: @MattDMo thanks, done.