# Reptiles are a paraphyletic group because?

Tags: zoology, homework

Here is a question I am trying to find the answer to

> Reptiles are a paraphyletic group because... ?
>
> A) They include worm lizards, which have no limbs
>
> B) The group doesn’t include birds
>
> C) The group doesn’t include mammals
>
> D) Not all of them have three- chambered hearts

I’m a bit confused about the reasoning. I know a paraphyletic group does not have all of its descendants so if birds were to be included it would become monophyletic. So is B the answer? Could anyone help explain it better?

Comment: I think the question's phrasing is a little wobbly, which make it a little hard to understand. But I think you understood what your teacher was expecting. I agree with you, answer is B.

Answer (score 5):

I think the question's phrasing is arguably a little wobbly, typically as to the nature of what someone would mean by the term "reptile". But I think you understood what your teacher was expecting. I agree with you, answer is B.

**[Reptilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reptile)** is a clade (clade = monophyletic group) that encompasses all species that we traditionally classify as reptiles + all birds. Hence, our traditional definition of reptile makes up for a paraphyletic group as birds aren't included.

Related post: [If dinosaurs could have feathers, would they still be reptiles?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35370/if-dinosaurs-could-have-feathers-would-they-still-be-reptiles)

Comment: To me it seems "Reptiles are a paraphyletic group because the group doesn’t include birds" is fine and not the least "wobbly", assuming Reptiles != Reptilia.